# SQLLDR with mix of fixed and variable-length fields

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to load an example datafile with records like this:

```
12312^123456^0015GRAJ1M7J0002^SOME GIBBERISH                    ^123
```

I need to associate this 5 fields with 6 database columns, where the first record is broken into 2:

`'12312' -> '123' and '12'`

and the rest of the fields are "^" separated.

What I have now is:

```
    COL_ONE POSITION(1:3) INTEGER EXTERNAL,
    COL_TWO POSITION(4:5) CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
    COL_THREE INTEGER EXTERNAL TERMINATED BY "^",
    COL_FOUR CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
    COL_FIVE CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
    COL_SIX CHAR TERMINATED BY "^"
    ....
```

but this doesn't work as expected as for some reason field

```
"SOME GIBBERISH                    "
```

ends up being inserted in COL_SIX instead of COL_FIVE, which gives me an error.

My log shows:

```
   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
COL_ONE                               1:3     3           CHARACTER            
COL_TWO                               4:5     2   ^       CHARACTER            
COL_THREE                            NEXT     *   ^       CHARACTER            
COL_FOUR                             NEXT     *   ^       CHARACTER            
COL_FIVE                             NEXT     *   ^       CHARACTER            
COL_SIX                              NEXT     *   ^       CHARACTER
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your third field:

```
COL_THREE INTEGER EXTERNAL TERMINATED BY "^"
```

This field starts at position 6, which unfortunately contains a `^` so this field will be filled with a NULL value, pushing all following fields into the wrong columns.

You could use a [filler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#sthref946) to ignore the `^` character at position 6:

```
COL_ONE POSITION(1:3) INTEGER EXTERNAL,
COL_TWO POSITION(4:5) CHAR,
dummy FILLER POSITION(6:6),
COL_THREE INTEGER EXTERNAL TERMINATED BY "^",
COL_FOUR CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
COL_FIVE CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
COL_SIX CHAR TERMINATED BY "^"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vincent, I've just come up with a solution to this, I tried your solution and it works too.

Comment: @Kris: your solution makes more sense =)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, problem solved with trial and error:

```
COL_ONE POSITION(1:3) INTEGER EXTERNAL,
COL_TWO CHAR TERMINATED BY "^",
.....
```